# spring boot jpa open-in-view false. How to convert existing application to not use OSIV?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There are lot of articles why not to use OSIV in production. Unfortunately, my app is finished and I have used open-in-view:true all the time of development because that's default setting and I did not know this. Please, could you give me an advice how to convert the whole application by the easiest way?

Should I use

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

in every controller and call the **NativeQuery**?

Or do you have some example of spring boot application **without** OSIV? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's no easy task. If you rely on lazy loading outside of the data layer, you will have to rework the data layer to fit all those needs. The easiest way is to use `@EntityGraph` on your repository methods to do the fetching of associations. Sometimes you will have to duplicate methods for different use cases to apply different `@EntityGraph` annotations. There are still some issues you can run into in such a design, but this should get you pretty far already.

IMO the best solution is to use DTOs as this will improve the performance when done right and eliminates all lazy loading issues. The "problem" is though, that this approach might require quite a few changes in your application.

Either way, I would recommend you take a look at what [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has to offer as a way to implement a DTO approach.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
UserDto findOne(Long id);
```

Using Entity-Views will improve performance immediately as it will only fetch the state that is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have chosen the @EntityGraph option even before you answered. I completely rebuild my app (DB loadings) which took me one day but it is done now. Anyway, I think it is strange from spring boot team that this very important feature (with potential impact and risk) is enabled by default. Increasing popularity? :) ...omg. But this is for another discussion of course.

Comment: There is an issue in the spring data Github repository about this, containing hundreds of comments about why they think it should be enabled vs. disabled by default.